# Is it possible to Consolidate sites?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010

I am a B.A. being tasked with solutions Sharepoint 2010 for our department.

The initial request is to consolidate many project sites of past/present into one single source site.

Is this possible in Sharepoint Server 2010?  How would I approach the request?

Comment: Thank-you for the Input.  Let me refine the objective.  Say there are 5 site collections full of various documents and content.  There is an ASK to consolidate certain Final documents(those in production vs. work in progress) to allow for Audit to review in a single place and have a Golden copy so to speak.  The Consolidated site would need to have full versioning history and functionality of the original which will remain on it's home site.  Any solution to accomplish this task for applicable documents would need to be vetted for feasibility.  The project is at the department level.

Comment: Cont'd from above:  There may not be an SME/developer available for this project, thus it may come down to a manual effort.  If so, I need to know the considerations and feasibility of the above proposal.  Any that can provide insight, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Very carefully. Often, people are trying to do the opposite, and split one site into many.

So first, I would take a site inventory. Find out how many sites, how many libraries, how many documents, and the average sizes of the documents. If you're combining multiple libraries into one library, then look into the "list view threshold", which is 5000 items by default. Meaning, any library with more than 5000 items requires special care and feeding.

Second, if multiple site collections are being combined into one site collection, then check into limitations on the content database size.

Third, look into how users currently navigate to files across multiple sites, and how they would navigate to files if they were in one site (and perhaps one library).

Fourth, look into permissions. Do different users have different permissions on the different sites? If so, how will that permission structure be maintained while moving to a single site?

But otherwise, you can do a manual migration, which is just users copying files from one site to another. Or, if you're moving things around in a single site collection, you can use the "site content and structure" feature to move files from one site to another. If you're moving sites around from one site collection to another, and you don't want to use the manual method, then look into 3rd party tools, like share-gate.

Make sure you do a test copy first, and lots of little things can go wrong. For example, perhaps every site has a document called "project requirements". Having a bunch of files with the same name is going to cause issues if you're moving all files to a single library.

Answer (score 1):

No OOTB consolidation option available in Sharepoint, that's why it is highly recommended to plan it accordingly. 
If data is on multiple site collections then you can bring those site collections as subsite under a single site collection.

there are couple of things you can think.

- Use the 3rd party tools ( ShareGate / Metalogix etc.), they will help to move site collection to as subsites.
- you can use export and import function to move the sites from one site collection to other but you will lose the metadata.
- If it is all about files then you can manually move these using open with explorer option.